# Change embeded TableViewController's data from parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm attempting to let the user press one of the names at the top. When they have done so, the child TableViewController will change a boolean `currentUserIsLoggedInUser`.

[image: storyboard]

In my `FactsController` I have the code:

```
class FactsController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentUserName: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendUserName: UIButton!

    var currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser: Bool = false

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ChangePersonSegue") {

            let embed: FactsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FactsTableViewController
            embed.currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser = self.currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser
            embed.refresh //this doesn't call the function like id want it to
        }
    }

    func changeFactList() {
        //segue for table view controller for ___
        // call prepareForSegue
        performSegueWithIdentifier("ChangePersonSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //changethings(user)
    }

    @IBAction func tappedUserName (sender: UIButton) {
        if currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser {

        }
        else {
            currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser = true
            changeFactList()
            currentUserName.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            friendUserName.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func tappedFriendName (sender: UIButton) {
        if currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser {
            currentPersonSelectedIsCurrentUser = false
            changeFactList()
            // change text color
            currentUserName.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            friendUserName.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Then in my `FactsTableViewController` I have the code:

```
class FactsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "factCell"

    var currentUserIsLoggedInUser: Bool = false

    //var currentUserName: String = ""
    var facts = [Fact]()
    var currentUser: User!
    var soUser: User!

    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if currentUserIsLoggedInUser {
            // make tableview for the current user
        }
        else {
            // make tableview for the friend         
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

If there's a way to just send from the `FactsController` a boolean when a button is pressed, that would make everything much easier.

Comment: It doesn't change a Boolean, it's a whole new view controller

Comment: Do you want the other other ViewController to know that something from previous controller has happened and it should change its boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want:

> a way to just send from the FactsController a boolean when a button is
>   pressed

then you need a delegate. The storyboard doesn't give you much control over this situation though. I'd move your UI in nib files and add `FactsTableViewController` manually as a child VC. Having instances of these classes you can manage delegates easier.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit new to swift. When you say "I'd move your UI in nib files" what do you mean?

Comment: No problem. There are several ways to represent your User Interface. When you use .storyboard file it usually contains all your screens and manages transitions. The "old" way is to use .xib files. You would have one .xib file per each screen and it would contain only one view. This approach requires you to manage all transitions between screens.
In your case you would have: `FactsController.swift`, `FactsController.xib`, `FactsTableViewController.swift`, `FactsTableViewController.xib`.
I suggest you to search for topics "storyboard vs xibs" and "how to remove storyboards from your project"